# How to retrive more than 10k lines from InfluxDB using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, influxdb, influxdb-python

I am trying to use InfluxDB's Python client's to retrieve data stored on InfluxDB, but can't more than 10k lines. The examples I am (unsuccessfully) following are [here](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#tutorials-pandas). In summary:

```
import influxdb
dfclient = influxdb.DataFrameClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'mydb')
q = "select * from some_measurement"
df = dfclient.query(q, chunked=True)  # Returns only 10k points
```

The issue seems to be related to InfluxDB's internal limitations documented [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/guides/querying_data/) (namely, the `max-row-limit` configuration option). I am going through the [sources](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python) to try to find out how to get a DataFrame larger than 10k lines, but any help in solving this issue would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `DataFrameClient`'s `query` simply ignoring the `chunked` argument [[code](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/blob/1a7e0fa54c54540fbd0e55108f82074a9a8b6b73/influxdb/_dataframe_client.py#L134)].

The workaround I found out is not use the standard `InfluxDBClient` instead. The code shown in the question becomes:

```
import influxdb
client = influxdb.InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'btc')
q = "select * from some_measurement"
df = pd.DataFrame(client.query(q, chunked=True, chunk_size=10000).get_points())  # Returns all points
```

It is also worth highlighting that from v1.2.2 the `max-row-limit` setting (i.e. the default value for `chunk_size` in the above code) has been change from 10k to unlimited.

Comment: I have just sent a [pull request](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/pull/439) to fix the handling of chunked requests by `DataFrameClient`.

Answer (score 3):

have you attempted to set the chunked flag on your query to receive the data back in chunks. This can be done using a query like the following:

```
influxdb.DataFrameClient(host='localhost', port=8086, username='root', password='root', database=None, ssl=False, verify_ssl=False, timeout=None, use_udp=False, udp_port=4444, proxies=None)
```

you can read more about it [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/influxdb-python/latest/influxdb-python.pdf) in section 1.2.3